# How to sort data from a file to the top 5 scores

Tags: python, file, sorting, text

I am not sure how to get my file to sort and display the top 5 scores from my text file.
Text file below :

```
24fred
23alan
24bert
28dan
11orange
17purple
16dave
22andy
```

The code which I am using to write to the file.

Tried using sort but can't get it to display only the top 5 scores.

```
file = open("Score.txt", "a")
file.write(str(name))
file.write(str(Score))
file.write("\n")
file.close
```

the file will print out sorted and only showing the top 5

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] for this problem.

Comment: If you work on Unix, you don't even need python to do this, just run:
`sort -n -r Score.txt | head -5`

Comment: Could you add the code that you use for the sorting step? I think your question can be answered very quickly, but this code is required!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following sample:

```
import re

pat = re.compile(r"^(\d+)(\D+)$")
def sort_crit(i):
    m = pat.match(i)
    return - int(m.group(1)), m.group(2)


with open("Score.txt",'r') as f:
  lines = [line.rstrip() for line in f]
  lines.sort(key = sort_crit)
  with open('Sorted_score.txt', 'w') as f:
    for item in lines:
        f.write("%s\n" % item)
```

**input:**

```
$ more Score.txt
24fred
23alan
24bert
28dan
28abc
11orange
17purple
16dave
22andy
```

**output:**

```
$ more Sorted_score.txt
28abc
28dan
24bert
24fred
23alan
22andy
17purple
16dave
11orange
```

**Explanations:**

- `re.compile(r"^(\d+)(\D+)$")` will be used to extract individually the score and the name
- `sort_crit(i)` will return the double sorting criteria based first on the score in reverse order (note the `-`), followed by the name in alphabetic order
- You open the input file and store all the lines in an array
- You sort the lines using the sorting function you have defined
- you output them in a new file

Comment: File "main.py", line 340, in <module>
    file.sort()
AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'sort' 

Any ideas ?